# Change Window Frame Style tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So I recently downloaded a skin for the program Steam and it changes the, "Window Frame", not sure what to call it. But I wanted to know if I could configure that, or if there is a way to cheat it like putting a custom made one on top of to appear as it is.

[Steam skin -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hzmb.png) 
[Tkinter Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeSUd.png)